# Outputting the wrong counts of like

Tags: facebook-like

I have an issue with facebook like. I want to make an fql query to get the count of likes on page say http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.mysite.com/index.php?data1=1&data2=2. But testing, I put that in my browser and I get the wrong count of likes and the json output takes as an id parameter  {..."id": "http://www.mysite.com/index.php?data1=1"...}, throwing away the data2 parameter. Why is the process wrong ? (knowing mysite is also a facebook app and this page has og metas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to encode the `& character in your query:

`http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.mysite.com/index.php?data1=1%26data2=2`
 works as expected

Comment: Thank you but when I put the link on my browser, I have 'url','type',... but no 'shares' entry in my json file. How is it possible ?

Comment: That's unrelated; what does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say about the URL? are you sure you're not stripping some of the passed-in parameters when setting your `og:url` value?

Comment: yep, indeed the url specified was not really fit. Thanks for all